# Deploying Python Flask app on web using pythonanywhere

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere

I want to deploy my flask app publicly using pythonanywhere. I have followed all steps exactly. Tried implementing it with virtualenv and without virtualenv but none works.

I can get the simple flask page 'Hello to flask app" working but my code is not working.

Path is /home/anwaraliafshan/bella and file is afshan.py

This is my WSGI.py and I tried replacing flask with bella and afshan but nothing worked. 
Also getting import imutil error in error.log though install imutil successfully on python3
Please help me finding the cause. Thanks in advance

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Flask project

import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/anwaraliafshan/bella/'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from flask import app as application  # noqa
```

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/) full solutions . `sys.path` is wrong defined by you (see examples in tutorial)

Comment: Don't call your file flask.py. Rename it to something else, because flask right now could be referring to both the module and the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As quoted from their [website](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/):

```
import sys
path = '/home/yourusername/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.insert(0, path)

from flask_app import app as application
```